# Loading a class with no defined namespace with Doctrine 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to load a class from a file with no namespace? I have one class inside doctrine\models which looks like this:

```
namespace models; //This was registered in the Bootstrap.php

...
....
$x = new ClassFromRandomFile();
...
....
```

ClassFromRandomFile looks like this:

```
<?php class ClassFromRandomFile {
      ... ...
}
```

Now, since ClassFromRandomFile does not have a defined namespace, Doctrine classLoader is attempting to load it from models, instead of from its real path, and hence it's not finding it, and returning `Fatal error: Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader::loadClass(): Failed opening required /path/to/doctrine/models/ClassFromRandomFile.php` ... How can I make that class find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply do

```
$x = new \ClassFromRandomFile();
```

by prepending the backslash you tell PHP to look for the class in the root namespace (which is none)

Comment: yeah I had figured this out, but thanks for your time, I accepted the answer since this is it.